# Django: No post found matching the query when creating a post

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, slug

I just got slugs to work for my Post model using django-autoslug. But i'm now experiencing this error when i try to create a new post:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/post/new/
Raised by:  blog.views.PostDetailView
No post found matching the query
```

Post Model

```
       class Post(models.Model):
            
            title = models.CharField(max_length=100)   
            author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', null=True)
        
            def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
                super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            
            def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, 'author': self.author})
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(author__username=self.kwargs['author'])
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request the `/post/new` URL, then this will match the `post-detail` view, since it can match `post` with the `author`, and `new` with the `slug`.

You should reorder the url patterns, such that it first matches the `post-create` view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<str:author>/<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

By first specifying the `post-create` view, if a user visits `/post/new/`, it will thus trigger the `post-create` view.

This thus also means that an author named `post` can not write an article named `new`, since then it will not trigger the `post-detail` view.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of cheated, but I ditched slugs, and I have my website go to tachlis.herokuapp.com/item_id/title_slug (for example http://tachlis.herokuapp.com/552/curb-your-veganism), and then my urls.py is 'int:pk/str:pkv/', and I use the item id ('pk') to get the right item, not the slug.